# How can I know the number of asymptotes of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions

I want to know that given function has how many asymptotes, I am trying this one

asymptotes `y = x^3`

giving me answer `x^3` not the numbers of asymptotes

Here my function is `y=x^3`. Any suggestion please.

Comment: For vertical asymptotes, you could probably use `FunctionDomain[]` to help you in determining them; for horizontal asymptotes, you could check the limits at infinity with `Limit[]`.

Comment: As I understand the term "asymptote", `y == x^3` doesn't have any.

Comment: Are you sure you are posting this question on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 1):

The number of vertical asymptotes could be any natural number including $0$, and could be found as roots to the inverted function. The number of  nonvertical asymptots could $0,1,2$, to be found the obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of remarks -

Using Wolfram Alpha "asymptotes x^3" returns "(no asymptotes found)" which is probably what you were looking for, but using "asymptotes y=x^3" returns "y=x^3 is asymptotic to y=x^3".  So, clearly, the first syntax is what you want.

Horizontal or oblique asymptotes are related to the end behavior of a function, so there are at most 2 (possibly one each as $x\rightarrow$ $+\infty$ and $-\infty$).  Vertical asymptotes arise from isolated singularities of a function.  In the case of a function like $\tan x$ there may be infinitely many ($x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ for any integer $k$), but in the case of a rational function the number of vertical asymptotes is at most the degree of the denominator of the rational function.  So for $x^3$ that must be zero.